# char* array's base address in c++

Tags: c++, arrays

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    char* str = "geek";

    //why is this not giving base address of str i.e. (int*)str
    cout<<&str[0];

    //output:
    //geek

    return 0;
}
```

I think that printing `&str[0]` should give address of the `0`<sup>th</sup> element that is same as `(int*)str`, base address. 
Please explain.

Comment: Why is this question tagged `c`?

Comment: How do you know it "doesn't give" it? Post the reproducing code.

Comment: `operator<<(const char*)` assumes its parameter is a pointer to a NUL-terminated string, and prints that string. If you want to print the address itself, make it `cout<<(void*)(&str[0)];`

Comment: [Not the Issue] You should turn up your warning settings.  `char* str = "geek";` is not standard conforming as it violates const correctness.

Comment: The 5-byte character sequence "geek\0" is declared in static memory. 
Your variable str simply points to that memory.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`&str[0]` *do* give you the address of the first character. *However* the type of that is `char*` which is interpreted as a null-terminated string, and the corresponding `char*` overload of the `<<` operator will be used to print it as a string.

You need to convert the pointer to a more generic type, like `void*`:

```
static_cast<void*>(&str[0])
```

On a very related note, don't forget that `&str[0]` is *exactly* equal to plain `str`.

Also don't forget that in C++ literal strings are really *constant* literal strings, and so `str` should be of type `char const*` (or the more common `const char*`).

Comment: isnt  "**has** to be `char const*`" more correct? I only know that it changed in c++11, but not sure what is the status now (deprecated?,ub?)

Comment: @user463035818 Not writing to it should be fine. (Don't get me wrong, I'm a big fan of const correctness.)

Comment: @Swordfish ah ok, then "should" actually is the right word, thanks :)

Comment: I prefer the `char const*` placement of `const` because the general rule being "const binds to the thing to its immediate left" rather than the exception-to-the-rule "...unless it is the first thing, then it binds to the thing to its immediate right" causes more confusion for any type that is more complex then a simple single type.  (Including something as complex as a `char*`.)